# What is the actual content of a non-booted hard drive

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot

I am trying to modify some Windows and Linux (obviously I'm talking of several computers, not only one) files. I know their path, but their location is just a fake location which is actually accessible when the hard drive is mounted, but when I read the hard drive with another OS and try to find my files, the content is not the same.

I already know this is because what I am seeing is the Boot Loader and the System data.
I just saw Windows disk content by the moment and I can't find nowhere where the booted content is, I mean, what I see when I boot my computer. Where is it? Both Linux and Windows.

Comment: By fake location do you mean a symbolic link? You can actually get those in Windows. I use one or two myself, for having files in the backed-up directories. In linux generally you do `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/win_c` or sdb2 or whichever partition.

Comment: @bgStack yeah I actually then mounted them one by one to check whether they were or not. But the thing about ntfs was helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I know. Windows disks have multiple partitions. One is to boot the system, the other one is to save the data, which is what I wanted, and finally the last one is some strange data which I wasn't able to find out what it is for.